# выполнение скрипта при переходе на новую страницу

Tags: javascript

на сайте реализована такая функция: при клике в таблице на имя браузер отправляет нас на другую страницу сайта вот таким образом `custom/?view=purchases&search=Tester`, где Tester это имя пользователя.
В инпут поиска вводится Tester
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но сам поиск не производится, что б он заработал нужно кликнуть по инпуту и нажать любую кнопку.

Как сделать так что б поиск выполнялся автоматически после перехода на эту страницу?

Comment: видимо поиск срабатывает на `onblur`. Посмотрите скрипт который обрабатывает данный `input`

Comment: Правильным решением будет исправить бэкенд, чтобы он делал поиск, если ему передали строку поиска.